# Android "toast" command explanation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, spinner

```
public void someClass(AdapterView<?>arg0,View arg1,int arg2,long arg3)     
         {
              Toast.makeText(arg0.getContext(), "<SOME STRING> 
               "+arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
          }
```

Can you please explain how does this piece of code work.What does this piece of code does.I am creating a simple spinner application and wanted to understand the "toast" command syntax!.

Comment: Have you tried reading the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html)?

Comment: Read this one: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Comment: have you tried running it in the emulator or on a device?

Answer (score 0):

A "toast" is the name for the small helper string display that gets shown after some action. An example is the sent successfully message in gmail.

The above function will create a toast with 'Some String' in it and display it for a 'Short' length of time within the context provided.